# SQL QUERY:Repeated Occurrences of user-login after (and including) first occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find repeated occurrences of user login from `loginhistory` table after a given date. I tried following query, but it gives ZERO rows.  `loginhistory` table has tow columns namely `userkeyid`, `datecreated`. Below is the query I am using:

Problem Statement:

**User logged in first time on or after `2013-10-26` and after logging in first time, all the repeated occurrences should be displayed till date. This should happen for all users who logged in first time on or after `2013-10-26` **

```
SELECT
    FirstOccurenceHistory.firsttimeuserkeyid userkeyid,
    firstOccurrenceDate,
    DATE(fullhistory.dateCreated) repeatedOn
FROM (
      SELECT DATE(dateCreated) firstOccurrenceDate,
          COUNT(1) n,
          userkeyid firsttimeuserkeyid
      FROM
          loginhistory
      GROUP BY userkeyid
      HAVING COUNT(userkeyid) = 1 and firstOccurrenceDate >= DATE('2013-10-26')
     )
    as FirstOccurenceHistory
INNER JOIN loginhistory fullhistory
    ON fullhistory.userkeyid = FirstOccurenceHistory.firsttimeuserkeyid
    AND DATE(fullhistory.dateCreated) > FirstOccurenceHistory.firstOccurrenceDate;
```

Comment: If you want repeated occurrences, why do you have "having count(userkeyid) = 1"?

Comment: I updated the problem statement clearly. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You overengineered it.  How about:

```
select f1, f2, etc, count(*) records
from loginhistory join other tables as necessary
where datecreated >= date('2013-10-26')
group by f1, f2, etc
having count(*) > 1
```

**Edit starts here**

To restrict this to those who logged in for the first time on or after that date, add the following to the from clause of the above query

```
 join (select useridkey userid, min(datecreated) mindate
 from loginhistory
 group by useridkey
 having min(datecreated) >= date('2013-10-26')
 ) temp on userid = useridkey
```

Comment: I updated the problem statement clearly. Please have a look.\